# Возможна ли работа с несколькими пользователями не используя БД?

Tags: php

Сервер должен уметь работать с несколькими пользователями(для каждого вывести сколько раз он заходил на сайт и когда был последний раз).Возможно ли это сделать без использования БД?

Comment: А что такое "пользователь" ? Он как то авторизуется ? Если нет - можете хранить в куках прямо на клиенте. Если да - то в любом удобном виде на сервере в привязке к данными авторизации

Comment: Только вводит имя фамилию и возраст

Comment: Их то же можно в куки. Они ведь уникально все равно пользователя не идентифицируют. Если у вас будет 2 Ивановых 1991 г.р. вы их друг от друга не отличите. Считать их одним пользователем никак нельзя

Comment: у меня есть куки для имени,фамилии,возраста,даты последнего визита и их количество,получается я не могу сделать так,что для каждого пользователя будет свой счетчик,который не обновляется при смене пользователя?

Comment: Это как работает у меня : я ввел Иванов и он три раза вошел с одного компьютера,потом за этот комп сел Петров и у него теперь 1 вход,а если потом опять сядет Иванов у него будет 1 вход,возможно ли что бы у Иванова счетчик не обнулялся?

Comment: Возможно. Ведите более сложную куку. В одной куке вполне можно закодировать информацию о том какие пользователи в принципе работали и каковы их счетчики и даты последнего входа

Comment: к сожалению не могу понять как это реализовать(

Comment: Сделайте массив где ключом будет Фамилия и год рождения, а значение - счетчик и дата последнего входа, например через запятую. И в куку кладете его в виде строки, например полученной с помощью serialize. Когда читаете куку разворичиваете массив обратно с помощью unserialize. В принципе так можно в одну куку включить вообще всю нужную информацию

Comment: PHP - язык, [рождённый умирать](https://habr.com/en/post/179399/), поэтому если вам нужна персистентность, то особо ничего не поделаешь. Советы с кукой действуют только для клиентской стороны (читай: для одного компьютера). В общем, для меня эта задача никакого практического смысла не имеет, это чистый изврат: придёте на реальное предприятие -- там будет нормальная база. Любая. Хоть в текстовом файле, хоть постгре/майскуль. А так чисто из любви к искусству пытаться решить задачу, но тогда нужно чётко понимать условия задания.

Answer (score 1):

БД - всего навсего способ хранения данных, если можно так выразиться.
Вам ничего не мешает, если требует задача, хранить инфу о пользователях в простом файле (txt, csv ... ). И используя php считывать его, редактировать его. И он будет у вас своего рода "База данных".

Comment: В задании вообще не должно быть файлов кроме index.php :(

Comment: в задании сказано без БД или без файлов? в любом случае можно тот же index.php использовать:) или внешний сервис. Или, к примеру, [pingfs](https://tproger.ru/articles/pingfs-by-yarrick/).